# Difference between AJAX Helper and async/await

Tags: asp.net, ajax, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-mvc-5

While reviewing the tutorial videos by Scott Allen on Plural Sight:

[Building Applications with ASP.NET MVC 4](http://www.pluralsight.com/courses/table-of-contents/mvc4-building) and [ASP.NET MVC 5 Fundamentals](http://www.pluralsight.com/courses/aspdotnet-mvc5-fundamentals)

I came across 2 different terms: `AJAX Helper` and `async/await`.

It "sounds" to me both operate on the asynchronous mode (correct me if I'm wrong). What exactly is the difference between each?

Comment: `async/await` is server side way of doing in async manner, internally thread takes over work, but with `ajax`, it is client side way to doing same, browser does that, i.e. sends `XMLHTTPRequest`, success callback is hit, once response reached to client.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

They are actually completely different. The key to understanding the difference is to think about the HTTP protocol.

In the HTTP protocol, you have one request and one response. That's it. The client makes a request, and the server creates and sends a response.

When you use `async` and `await` in a request handler (such as an MVC action), you still only have one response. `async` doesn't change the HTTP protocol. So, what `async`/`await` does is free up the request thread while there is asynchronous work being done. But while that asynchronous work is being done, nothing is sent to the client (the response is not yet created). You can think of `async`/`await` as "yielding" to the ASP.NET runtime, but not the client browser.

AJAX is a different approach. AJAX is a convention for issuing *additional* HTTP requests from a browser, without changing the current page. You'd use AJAX if you're writing a SPA, or say, if you wanted to load a "placeholder" page and *then* load the content.

For more information, see the "Asynchronous Code Is Not a Silver Bullet" section of [my MSDN article on async ASP.NET](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dn802603.aspx).

Comment: Is this still the case with .Net Core MVC? I noticed async being used in the controller methods of a Core MVC application and I wonder if this is replacing Ajax. I come from MVC 5 background, and transitioning to core.

Comment: This is still the same. `async` cannot *ever* change the HTTP protocol. AJAX (though usually without XML these days) is one option when doing multiple requests. Other choices can include other protocols such as websockets.